# email body not taking carriage returns

Tags: php, email, carriage-return

I'm sendoing an email in PHP and trying to add a few carriage returns but when I get the email, the carriage returns on the `$message` don't seem to work, am I doing this properly?

```
$message = "Dear ".$row['user']." \r\nThe report you ran (".$row['report_name'].") has finished \r\nThanks\r\nMatchmaker.";

    $subject = "Report has finished successfully";
    
    $headers = "From: test@test.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: test@test.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";


    mail($row[login], $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: You're sending it as HTML, which does not process the carriage returns. Use `<br>` instead

Comment: (Or send it as text.)